# If i sent the following response to my browser, am I supposed to get any kind of feedback?

Tags: java, html, io, stream

For an assignment, I have written a server that services HTML files and I am supposed to use my web browser as a test client. I am also told that if there is a request for a file that doesn't exist i should send the following
`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n` and if anything else goes wrong

`HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error\r\n\r\n"`

I have run tests that should cause those to be sent, but nothing occurs in my browser window? Should I be getting any visual feedback from sending such a request?

Comment: It depends on the browser - but generally, yes. Use a tool like Firebug to ensure that a *correct* HTTP result is being returned.

Comment: I don't know what FireBug is

Comment: Google does. Also see "IE Developer Tools" or whatever the equivalent is for Safari/Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an HTML response there should only be one CRLF (carriage return and line feed) after each line. So you can first remove the extra `\r\n`.

Also on the second line you can send an HTML response back to the client saying what the error was if you want to show an error. This is normally what a typical web server does where it has its default error page if one is not defined. If you are not sending any HTTP headers, then you can insert the HTML body you want to send back such as `<h1> No page found</h1>` as the second line.

Comment: you need CRLF CRLF to end the response head.

Answer (score 0):

To include an "entity" in an http response

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 10

01234576789
```

each line is ended by CRLF. Be sure to count the Content-Length correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this is a learning exercise, and understand that you *may* have been *told* to implement the server this way.  But bearing that in mind ...

---

This is the wrong way to implement a web server / service.  The right way is to find an existing implementation and build your service on top of that.

- You could use a Java EE web container; i.e. something that implements the Servlets spec.
- You could use a non-servlet framework (like Grizzly).
- You could build on top of a server-side HTTP protocol stack; e.g. using Apache the HttpComponent library.

Building a web server from the ground up is a lot of work if you are going to do it properly.  And the chances that you won't do it properly; i.e. you won't implement your service according how the HTTP spec says a server should behave.  You will leave things out, do things the wrong way, etc.

Please don't do it.  There are already too many broken (i.e. non-compliant) web servers out there.  We don't need more.

And if you DO decide to implement HTTP from the ground up, then you (YOU) need to thoroughly read and *understand* the HTTP spec.  And you (YOU) need to do your own basic research on how browsers implement the client side of the spec ... and what you therefore need to do on the server side to make browsers behave "normally".